# tk.pack() vs root.mainloop()

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

Why doesn't tk.pack() work in pycharm? It works just fine in python 3.7 idle, but in pycharm you have to use tk.mainloop() or root.mainloop() or else a canvas or window won't pop up. I am using pycharm community edition. Can someone help?

Including both in the script works, but the tk.pack() seems to have no effect on the code. root.mainloop() works alone by itself, yet tk.pack() does not.

```
from tkinter import *

tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=500)
tk.mainloop()
```

Works but this doesn't:

```
from tkinter import *

tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=500)
tk.pack()
```

I expected tk.pack() to make a little window pop up, but nothing happens. Does anyone know why? Thanks.

Comment: Note that in your "working" example, the window that pops up does not actually contain your Canvas (because you never called `.pack()` or other geometry management method on it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I expected tk.pack() to make a little window pop up, but nothing happens. Does anyone know why?

It doesn't make a window pop up because that's not what `pack()` does. `pack` will arrange for a widget to be in another widget, but unless you call `mainloop` the widget will never appear. You must<sup>1</sup> call `mainloop` for anything to happen in your program.

In other words, `mainloop` and `pack` server two completely different purposes.

---

<sup>1</sup> *you must* is a bit strong. The mainloop needs to be running, but sometimes something else will cause it to run. For example, if you're running in an interactive prompt you don't need to call it. In general, however, something needs to make sure that `mainloop` is running. That is a fundamental part of using tkinter.